# Devirtualise Child Class Call

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a **Parent** class that implements a virtual method, overridden by a **Child** class. I understand that if the method is called on a variable of type **Parent** then the compiler must use some way of checking which implementation of the method should be called at run time, but surely this is not necessary if the variable is of type **Child**? In this case, assuming that the method is not overridden again by a child of **Child**,  will the compiler devirtualise the method since it is known that the variable will definitely contain a **Child**, and is this compiler specific?

Comment: What do you mean by "variable"? Clearly if the most-derived type is `Parent`, there's no need to dispatch anything: `Parent v;  v.f();` (Can be dispatched statically, calls `Parent::f`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to de-virtualize a call, the compiler would have to know for certain that there are no derived types of Child that it might be passing through the code with:

```
void f(Child* c) {
    Child* l = new Child;
    c->virtFn();
    l->virtFn();
}
```

The c call to virtFn could be for a derived type, but the l call can't.

C++11 introduced the final keyword that can assist with this and allow the compiler to devirtualize calls through a terminal class pointer/ref.

Comment: Good job calling out `final`: Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/g/SfKjsU) of the optimization.

Comment: I'm surprised that it isn't easy for the compiler to know whether any derived classes exist. Thanks for the `final` tip

Comment: @user3834847 the optimizer might, given sufficient options (eg whole program)